# Django : proper way to make website title editable in admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm building a website with Django. I have a main title for the website in my header template, currently hard-coded in it.

How can I make it editable in the admin by the website administrator (or any user with the right credentials) ? Ideally I'd also like to be able to make more such site-wide (or app-wide) attributes editable in the admin (such as site - or app- description, for instance).

I have in mind something like WordPress' [bloginfo()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) . A practical example of this is [washingtonpost.com](https://www.washingtonpost.com/) who changed their moto in their header to "Democracy dies in darkness" a few weeks ago.

Of course once the title (or any other attribute) has been edited in the admin I need to be able to get it from within my template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple model to store dynamic website parameters like this for example:

```
class WebsiteParam(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    val = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

Then define custom template context processor settings_processor.py

```
def settings_processor(request):
    vals = {x.key: v.val for x in WebsiteParam.objects.all()}
    return {'website_settings': vals}
```

Add this processor into your django settings.py something like:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    "myapp.settings_processor.settings_processor",
)
```

And you will be able to use your settings in all of your templates like

```
<html><head><title>{{website_settings.title}}</title>...
```

if you have settings with `title` key added into the database

You should of course add caching into request context processor and other conditions if necessary

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go this afternoon and will give some feedback here.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of instances of this model to one ? It doesn't make sense to have more than one.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I missed the logic of your answer. The problem I have is that website_settings.title doesn't work, because website_settings is a queryset, and I can only access individual settings by looping through all and selecting the one I want with an {% if %} statement. Any idea how to get around this ?

Comment: yes, sorry, missed that while entering my answer :) i have updated the code for request context processor. now it should work as expected. You can access value by its key in templates

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be useful to accept at least the edit for settings.py, as what you proposed doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am sorry I don't see an option to view edit... need to learn this site more ;)